Can we find a continuous $f$, such that $\int_{|z-a|=r}f(z)dz=0$ for any circle, but $f$ is not holomorphic

Can we find a continuous $f$, such that $\int_{|z-a|=r}f(z)dz=0$ for any circle, but $f$ is not holomorphic.

As we all know by Cauchy integral theorem that the converse  is true.
I think the statement above is not right, but could not figure out a conterexample...$\bar{z}$ $|z|^2$?

There’s a version of Morera’s theorem for circles too.
